# Not able to get detailed error trace from BulkResponse in Elasticsearch Nest Client

Tags: nest, elasticsearch-net

What I want is when bulk update using script, if there is conflict on data, throw a customized exception from the script. And client side can grab and handle that error. I expected the BulkResponse contains detailed error message containing my customized exception message, but it is not there.

I tried below, using Nest v2.3.1:

Using ElasticClient.Bulk to update data, in the script I throw a exception to let the response know what happened.

The source code I'm using:

```
//docs is a list of docmodel objects 
BulkRequest bulkRequest = new BulkRequest(_indexName)
        {    
            Operations = docs.Select(doc => (IBulkOperation)
            (
                new BulkUpdateOperation<leaddoc, leaddoc>(doc.id)
                {
                    RetriesOnConflict = RetryOnVersionConflict, 
                    Upsert = doc, // if doc not exist, upsert it and not run the script
                    Script = "use(java.lang.Exception) {throw new Exception(\"Custermized Exception\")}",
                }
            )).ToList()
        };

        IBulkResponse bulkResponse = await elasticClient.BulkAsync(bulkRequest);
        if (!bulkResponse.IsValid)
        {
            throw new Exception(bulkResponse.DebugInformation);
        }
```

In the IBulkResponse, the item error just show one level of error message which is Reason = "failed to execute script"

However, in the raw Json reponse, there is full error message like this:

```
{
    "update": {
        "_index": "testindex",
        "_type": "docmodel",
        "_id": "xyz",
        "status": 400,
        "error": {
            "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": "failed to execute script",
            "caused_by": {
                "type": "script_exception",
                "reason": "failed to run inline script [use(java.lang.Exception) {throw new Exception(\"Custermized Exception\")}] using lang [groovy]",
                "caused_by": {
                    "type": "privileged_action_exception",
                    "reason": null,
                    "caused_by": {
                        "type": "exception",
                        "reason": "Custermized Exception"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Question is: How can I get detailed error message from ElasticClient?

Or is there any better way to grab the exception?

(this question is re-posted because previous question is not clear enough)

Comment: I've opened an issue to address this - https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/2152. Currently, the client only deserializes the top level `caused_by`

Comment: Thank you very much. Looking forward for this fix.

Comment: This is now in NEST 2.4.2 - https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/releases/tag/2.4.2